# Adding elements to wp_list_pages (within <li>, but before <a>)

Tags: css, wp-list-pages, regex

I'm working on my first wordpress theme and I'm running into some trouble. I'd like to add an extra div (which I'll style in css) within each `<li>`, but *before* the actual `<a ... >` element

In my theme, I'm using `wp_list_pages('&sort_column=menu_order&link_before=<div></div>&title_li=');`, which results in *almost* what I want, but not quite. The out put I get from the method call above results in this:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/htdocs/wordpress/?page_id=2"><div></div>Page Name A</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-4 current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost/htdocs/wordpress/?page_id=4"><div></div>Page Name B</a></li>
```

as you can see, this places the `<div>` within the `<a>` and not before it.

I've tried using the CSS :before selector to do what I want, but it won't work in this instance because I am adding some styles to the `<li>`and `<a>` elements (some light skews) that I don't want to actually affect the new area that this makeshift div will use. (I've already tried reversing the skews and it didn't work for the :before selector)

I've also tried using a hacky regex to get this done: `echo preg_replace("/>\s*<a/i", "><div></div><a", (string)wp_list_pages('&sort_column=menu_order&title_li='));` but that still didn't work (which really puzzled me).

I know this is kind'of odd, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I Understood your question right, instead of wp_list_pages, you can use a custom query using get_pages e.g.

```
$args = array(
'sort_order' => 'ASC',
'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
'hierarchical' => 1,
'exclude' => '',
'child_of' => 0,
'parent' => -1,
'exclude_tree' => '',
'number' => '',
'offset' => 0,
'post_type' => 'page',
'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$pages = get_pages($args); 
foreach($pages as $page){
 echo '<li><div><a href="'.get_page_link( $page->ID ).'">'.$page->post_title.'</a></div></li>';
}
```

Some of the code in the $args could probably be removed though

Comment: That works perfectly and I apologize if I was a bit confusing. I should have put what I wanted as sample output to be more clear (my regex probably didn't help, especially because I just noticed it was wrong anyway). Thank you for letting me know of this method's existence and it's usage.